# R Data bar issue with the Year column in DT table

Tags: r, dt

I am creating an `xaringan` presentation via `RMarkdown` which includes a `DT` table consisting of `databars`. When I use the code below I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
```

Note that I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848270/dt-data-table-display-error) answer but wasn't able to work with it.

The purpose is to show the entire table with the Count column consisting of data bars along with the values as well.

Sample Data

```
Year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022)

City = c("Miami", "Miami", "Miami", "Orlando", "Orlando", "Orlando"

Count = c(10, 44, 33.5, 56, 65, 14, 78, 88)
```

Code

```
library(DT)

df = data.frame(Year, City, Count)

datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df),
                              background = styleColorBar(range(df[, "Count"]), 'lightblue', angle = -90),
                              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

UPDATE

I was able to solve the problem using:

```
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df),
                              background = styleColorBar(range(df$Count), 'lightblue', angle = -90),
                              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

It is showing the `databars` for the `Count` column. However, now the `Year` column is also showing completely filled `databars` as shown below.

How can I fix this so that the `Year` column does not show `databars`?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with **formatStyle** but what about replacing **names(df)** with the names of the columns for which you want the bars?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you but I already did that in the `styleColorBar` function. That's why I am confused as to why it's coloring the `Year` column.